# London Tube gadgets

Tags: windows-vista, desktop-gadget, sidebar

Are there any free London Tube information (service updates)  gadgets for Windows Vista sidebar?

Comment: what kind of information do you need?

Comment: service updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [London Underground Live Travelnews - Vista Sidebar](http://www.thomthom.net/gallery/gadgets/london-underground-live-travelnews-vista-sidebar/). It might work for you.

[image]

Or even [London Underground Gadget](http://www.thoosje.com/vista-sidebar-gadgets/tools-utilities/LondonUnderground.zip).